# Is it possible to use D3 word cloud on your (for profit) website for free?

Tags: copyright, website

I am trying to create a website using **React**, and I need to implement a **word cloud**.

Is the [D3 word cloud](https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud) free? I have read the [LICENSE](https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud/blob/master/LICENSE) file, and it says it is protected by copyright. I am not sure I fully understood all the terms, I am looking for more detailed information about how they will translate into practice.

Can you create a website and (eventually) make money with it using that tool for free?

Answer (score 2):

A quick comparison will show that the licence is the very common [three-clause BSD](https://directory.fsf.org/wiki/License:BSD-3-Clause) (3BSD) licence.  The author of the software has modified the licence to incorporate his actual name, which is unnecessary, but the rights granted are those granted by 3BSD.  I mention this because much is written about 3BSD, some or all of which may now be of use to you.

As I understand it, though, you will be fine taking this tool and using it to make word clouds on your website, even if you charge money for access to the site.